# Scroll on bottom divs

Tags: jquery, chat

I am working on my own chat. And on one main window I have more chat windows(divs). And I want when I load my main windows, that my chat divs was scrolled on bottom. Have you any solutions?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML/CSS/JavaScript to support your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);
```

this is your solution :D

http://jsfiddle.net/emx9D/

Comment: How can that be the solution? There is no code in the question to work with.

Comment: This works fine but only for one div. All of this divs I set id="div1". But this solution works only for first of this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/emx9D/

then use class for more div's :)

Comment: Thank you guys with class works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of different jQuery solutions that do this, take a look at them [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/)

The general gist of it, is browser detects you're at the bottom of the page, do an ajax query, append onto page.