# Javascript scroll always on bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div class called ".chat-scroll". I need that div class always on the bottom like chat.

```js
$(".chat-scroll").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```

```css
.chat-scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chat-scroll">
  <ul class="messages list-unstyled">
    <li><span class="text">{!! $shout->text !!}</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But does not working.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/5nsur4q2/1/

Comment: Better version: http://jsfiddle.net/5nsur4q2/10/

Comment: Thanks for answers. Really weird. Works fine, but only if i reload the page. If i move on another page and click on chat, scroll does not working. If i reload page, scroll works...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. One thing I noticed: you shouldn't be using the height of document. You should use the height of the `.messages` element. `$('.messages').height()` - http://jsfiddle.net/5nsur4q2/15/

Comment: Thanks u made me on the right way @Turnip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll on bottom divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695726/scroll-on-bottom-divs)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why didnt you use {position:fixed} ...

```
   .chat-scroll {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    }
```

I think probably you like to practice Jquery